# Why are asterisks needed for array variable?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, declaration

Looking at the code segment down below, array in C language is already a pointer saving the address of the first element of the array, so why the asterisk is needed for `argv` variable?

```c
char *argv[3]; 

argv[0] = "echo";
argv[1] = "hello";
argv[2] = 0;
exec("/bin/echo", argv);
printf("exec error\n");
```

Comment: What is the type of each individual element in that array?

Answer (score 5):

`argv` is an array of pointers to `char`. So `argv[0]` is a `char*`, as is `argv[1]`, and so on.

You read the type from highest-precedence operator outwards from the name being declared. Since `[]` (array operator) has higher precedence than `*` (indirection), you read it as:

- `argv`
- ...is an array (`[]`)
- ...of pointers (`*`)
- ...to `char`.

Answer (score 2):

This array declaration

```
char *argv[3];
```

declares an array with 3 elements of the type `char *`. That is elements of the array are pointers and these pointers (except the last) are assigned with addresses of first characters of string literals

```
argv[0] = "echo";
argv[1] = "hello";
argv[2] = 0;
```

To make it more clear you could declare the array for example the following way

```
char * ( argv[3] );
```

or

```
char * ( argv )[3];
```

Or for example using a typedef

```
typedef char * T;
T argv[3];
```

And the assignments can look like

```
argv[0] = &"echo"[0];
argv[1] = &"hello"[0];
argv[2] = NULL;
```

Comment: My bad... I was referring to the arguments to the `main` function :) In this particular case, the array should probably be defined as `const char *argv[3];`

Answer (score 2):

> array in C language is already a pointer

No, it "decays" to a pointer to the *first item* when used in most expressions. That doesn't make an array a pointer.

But in this case that's completely irrelevant, since the purpose is to create *an array of pointers* (to string literals).

Comment: @chqrlie The OP decided to name some array `argv` and (re)assign the pointers to string literals, check the code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C aren't actually pointers, but in many cases *decay* to a pointer to the first element in the array.

In this case, `argv` is an array of `char *`.  So each array element can hold a pointer to the start of a string.

Answer (score 0):

`char *argv[3]` is an array of 3 char pointers.

To put it another way, char *arg would be a single char pointer. A single char pointer could be `"hello".`

`int nums[3]` would be an array of 3 numbers. nums[0] could be 1, nums[2] be 2, and nums[2] be 3.

Therefore, `char *argv[3]` is an array that holds 3 char pointers. It can hold 3 char pointers like in your example.

You could technically use `char argv[][]` instead, and have an array *holding* an array of chars. The reason we don't do this is that the lengths of the char arrays are variable, and since array need a strictly-defined size, we'd like run into errors this way. Using pointers allows us to have variable sizes, which is what we want.